# `android.packageBuildConfig=false` is deprecated

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle, android-gradle-plugin

After upgrading Android studio to 4.0.1 I am getting this error

```
android {
compileSdkVersion 28

android.packageBuildConfig = false

defaultConfig {
minSdkVersion 11
}
```

While I try to compile I get the error

> Could not set unknown property 'packageBuildConfig' for extension 'android' of type com.android.build.gradle.LibraryExtension.

What is the alternative of packageBuildConfig? Thanks in advance

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can disable BuildConfig generation via **buildFeatures**

```
buildFeatures {
    buildConfig = false
}
```

[Source](https://developer.android.com/studio/releases/gradle-plugin#buildFeatures)